# Manually trigger Eclipse4 (e4) class'es method, which uses injections?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a class, which get a MApplication injected. It is a Handler. I want to trigger the Handler's methods manually.

**Problem**:
When I instantiate the Handler manually from another class - the MApplication is null. The class which I trigger the Handler from allready has an MApplication injected, so it is not a lifecycle problem.

**Question**:
How can I trigger a method in a class, which has @Inject annotated methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following made the day.

```
    ManipulateModelhandler man = new ManipulateModelhandler();

    //inject the context into an object
    //IEclipseContext iEclipseContext was injected into this class
    ContextInjectionFactory.inject(man,iEclipseContext);

    man.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter:

```
ContextInjectionFactory.make(ManipulateModelhandler.class, iEclipseContext).execute();
```

Or by executing the annotated method independent of its name (the way the framework does it):

```
ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(new ManipulateModelhandler(), Execute.class, iEclipseContext);
```